# Can we make an HTTPS call with self signed certificate and ATS enable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios9

It is possible to make HTTPS service call using a self signed Certificate with ATS enabled?

Since I am using the IP address instead of domain, I want to know *how to do the domain registration with the ATS*.

I also wanted to know whether Apple will reject my App if i use the Self Signed Certificate for making HTTPS call.